# How to show that it is true or false that a number belongs to the range of a two variable function defined on integers?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

For example if $f(x,y)=\frac{2x+1}{2y+1}$, how do you show it is true that $\frac{13}{11}$ is in the range of $f(x,y)$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$? In other terms, how do you show a solution to $f(x,y)=13/11$ can exist?

I tried solving $f(x,y)=13/11$ and the subtituting the solution

```
f[x_,y_]:=(2x+1)/(2y+1)
list=Replace[{x,y},Solve[f[x,y]==13/11,{x,y},Integers]]
f[list]=13/11
```

But instead of getting "true", it gives

```
Out[44]= {{x,y}}
Out[45]= 13/11
```

I also tried

```
13/11∈Range[f(x,y),{x,y},Integers]
```

But it gives

```
13/11∈True
```

I could not find other operators in the documentation that can be used. What other techniques are possible?

Comment: You need `ReplaceAll` instead of `Replace`.

Comment: I tried but it gives `{{ConditionalExpression[6+13C[1],(C[1]∈Integers&&C[1]≥0)||(C[1]∈Integers&&C[1]≤-1)],ConditionalExpression[5+11C[1],(C[1]∈Integers&&C[1]≥0)||(C[1]∈Integers&&C[1]≤-1)]}` instead of "true"

Comment: To check that something has the same value as something else, use `==` (fullform `Equal`), not `=` (fullform `Set`)

Comment: It gives a `ConditionalExpression` which means you need another assumption there. That `C[1]` is a sign that you have potentially multiple solutions, I think.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't catch that.

Comment: But first, do `Clear[f]` and try again, because you have now _defined_ `f[list]` to be 13/11.

Comment: And finally, in order to get the x and y you have solved for not as a **list** to f, like `f[{x, y}]`, but as first and second argument, use `Apply`: `f @@ list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to note is if you just need a way to check if there's a particular solution you can do this:

```
In[38]:= Resolve[
 Exists[{x, y},
  f[x, y] == 13/11
  ],
  Integers (* Per Carl Woll's comment *)
  ]

Out[38]= True
```

Comment: Since the OP specified a domain of `Integers`, you might want to use `Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, f[x, y] == 13/11], Integers]` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll yes indeed. I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use FindInstance. If this can find an example, then the number of solutions is greater than zero. If it can find no example, the length is zero.

```
f[x_, y_] := (2 x + 1)/(2 y + 1);
Length[FindInstance[f[x, y] == 13/11, {x, y}, Integers]]>0

True
```